# Join Two Tables with SUM on Second Table

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

This is such a silly question but I've been battling with it all day.

I have two tables.

```
products
+-----+---------+
| SKU | Quantity|
+-----+---------+
| ABC | 90      |
| DEF | 40      |
| XYZ | 33      |
+-----+---------+

    orders
    +-----+----------+
    | SKU | OrderID  |
    +-----+----------+
    | ABC | aaa      |
    | ABC | yyy      |
    | DEF | xxx      |
    | DEF | bbb      |
    | DEF | ccc      |
    +-----+----------+
```

I want the output to show all of the fields from table 1 and match the sum of the count of SKU from Table 2. If there's no match from table 2, it should return null or 0. So the output should be:

```
+-----+---------+-------+
| SKU | Quantity| Count +
+-----+---------+-------+
| ABC | 90      |  2    |
| DEF | 40      |  3    |
| XYZ | 33      |       |
+-----+---------+-------+
```

I wrote the following query (I'm using Laravel, so excuse the Laravel syntax)

```
$orders=Orders::groupBy('orders.SKU')
            ->selectRaw('sum(orders.quantity) as quantity_sum, orders.SKU');

$ordersAllProducts = DB::table('products')
    ->leftJoinSub($orders, 'orders', function ($join) {
        $join->on('products.SKU','=','orders.SKU');
    })->get();
```

It almost works, but I'm getting null for the SKU as shown below.

```
+-----+---------+-------+
| SKU | Quantity| Count +
+-----+---------+-------+
| ABC | 90      |  2    |
| DEF | 40      |  3    |
|     | 33      |       |
+-----+---------+-------+
```

Comment: is SKU unique in products?

Comment: Yes SKU is a unique field.

Answer (score 0):

Not completely familiar with this ORM but I believe you should say `products.SKU` here, not `orders`:

```
->selectRaw('sum(orders.quantity) as quantity_sum, orders.SKU');
                                                   ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Every join has two sides; a left and a right. When you LEFT JOIN you effectively say "give every row on the left, and maybe a matching row on the right, or null if there isn't a match". Orders is from the right side of the join, i.e. the side that is occasionally null

Comment: ps if you want 0 instead of null, try replacing `sum(orders.quantity) as quantity_sum` with `coalesce(sum(orders.quantity),0) as quantity_sum`

Answer (score 0):

I can provide you native query to get that 3 column result (mysql query)

- SKU
- Quantity
- count ( "-" if count = 0 )

```
$sql = "select SKU, Quantity, 
    (select IF(count(*) > 0  , count(*), "-") from orders o where o.SKU = 
     p.SKU) as count
      from products  p" ;

$result = DB::select($sql);
dd($result);
```

If you want to return 0 for zero counts instead of "-" just remove (if condition) from query